# Django allowed hosts with port number

Tags: python, django

I use django as a backend and it's running on 8000 port at the loopback interface. So, when I'am to try start it with DEBUG = False, I got 500 error on any request from a frontend.
I set my ALLOWED_HOSTS as:

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1:8000', 'localhost:8000', '*',]
```

But this doesn't work for me.
Is it possible disable this option or how I can do that?

**UPDATE**
So I just declared variable ALLOWED_HOSTS above of default ALLOWED_HOSTS = [].  Sorry for the inattention.

Comment: Normally, improper django ALLOWED_HOSTS should lead to ”Bad Request (400)”. could you provide more details?

Comment: @alko, Are you sure it should lead to HTTP 400? I'm pretty sure I'm getting HTTP 500s from all those pesky bots scanning IPs - more specifically `SuspiciousOperation` exception.

Comment: '*' rule should disable host validation at all. Are you sure that 500 error is related to ALLOWED_HOSTS?

Comment: Yes, I got messages like SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): 127.0.0.1:8000. But wildchar is in ALLOWED_HOSTS

Comment: Look [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#suspiciousoperation) and [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3bc0d46a840f17dce561daca8a6b8690b2cf5d0a/django/core/handlers/base.py#L172)

Answer (score 8):

Normally, improper django ALLOWED_HOSTS should lead to `”Bad Request (400)”`.

In more details, `DisallowedHost` (child class to `SuspitiousOperation`) is raised by request in `HttpRequest.get_host()`, and is processed later by [request hadler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3bc0d46a840f17dce561daca8a6b8690b2cf5d0a/django/core/handlers/base.py#L172), returning `400` HTTP response. You might get `500` error if an exception is occured in `resolver.resolve400()`.

@Denis may be you mangled ALLOWED_HOSTS. I'd suggest you debug its value (logging it for example). See how [validation works](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3bc0d46a840f17dce561daca8a6b8690b2cf5d0a/django/http/request.py#L507), your '*' should skip any host validation

Comment: your answer is not straight to the point. How is the OP is supposed to make it **proper** or better yet, **work**?

Comment: @eric I suggest you to read the answer and look at the question. It's obvious that the problem is not in the snippet provided, so the only solution is to debug, as I suggested. You could even check in the *UPDATE* that the suggestion helped ;)